# TypeScript Error Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Variable Y'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
sampleDataPayload = {
   accountInformation: {
      userId: '123';
      groupId: '123';
   }
}

type PayloadType = {
   accountInformation: {
      userId: String;
      groupId: String;
   }
}

export const functionApiName = async(payload: PayloadType) => {
    //...calling Api logic
}
```

Hi All,

I am beginner of typescript. I received the below error messages when run build. Can anyone guide me how should I declare the type of payload with the sample payload data i provided on above?

**TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PayloadType'.**
**Property 'accountInformation' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'PayloadType'.**

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work.
It might be the argument you pass into the function are non-Payload objects, E.G empty `{}`s.

This is resolved in my testcase at least because I am passing a sample data object in as the parameter, and `sampleDataPayload` **does** meet the conditions of being a `Payload` object.

`sampleData` is also stored as a var/object not class, so the `,` between variables and declaration of `var` would be required if that is the cause

```
var sampleDataPayload = {
   accountInformation: {
      userId: '123',
      groupId: '123'
   }
}

type PayloadType = {
   accountInformation: {
      userId: String;
      groupId: String;
   }
}
const functionApiName = async(payload: PayloadType) => {
    console.log(payload)
}
functionApiName(sampleDataPayload);
```